# Incorrect date fetched from Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jdbc-postgres

I have a field called `deadline_date` of type `timestamp with time zone` with value  `2018-05-03 19:00:00-05.`

```
select deadline_date from invoice_details where file_name='BHDHSB.pdf';

     deadline_date      
------------------------
 2018-05-03 19:00:00-05
(1 row)
```

But on querying from my java code it is returning the value as `2018-05-04 05:30:00+05:30` .

I think it is converting the the date according to my local timezone.

Is there any way to get the value as stored in the table?

I am using the following maven dependency for Postgres

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
     <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
     <version>9.4.1212</version>
</dependency>
```

Test.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class Test {
    public static Connection connection;
    public void createConnection()
    {
        try {
            if (connection==null) {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/abc", "abc", "Welcome");
                connection.setSchema("iiv_location");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            test object = new test();
            object.createConnection();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select iiv_prescan_invoice_details.deadline_date from iiv_prescan_invoice_details");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString("deadline_date"));
           }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Show us your Java code

Comment: Yes, it would be a Timezone problem... Show us the code...

Comment: BTW, the value is the same, just represented in a different timezone...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto yes. the value is same. but my requirement is to get the  value as stored in the table.  I have added my code in the question. Please check.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added code. please check

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `getString()` to retrieve a timestamp (actually: **only** use it for strings. Not for numbers, not for dates, not for timestamps).

If you are dealing with timestamps that are time zone aware, you should use a `OffsetDateTime` in Java.

The Postgres JDBC driver supports this directly through the `getObject()` method:

```
OffsetDateTime deadline = resultSet.getObject("deadline_date", OffsetDateTime.class);
```

Comment: Please Note: This `OffsetDateTime` and also the `LocalTDateTime` in another answer is from Java8 / YodaTime only.

Comment: No need for `OffsetDateTime`. **Postgres only stores moments in UTC** in a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, where can simply use `Instant` in Java. In a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, there is no zone or offset at all, not UTC, not anything, in which case use `LocalDateTime` in Java.

Comment: @BasilBourque: that's not entirely true. If you see how e.g. `psql` displays such a value, it includes the client's time zone. If you want a value that is similar to that, retrieving the timestamp as an OffsetDateTime does make sense to preserve the adjustment that Postgres does when retrieving such a value.

Comment: psql is opinionated, taking the liberty to apply that zone adjustment. That is a bad design choice in my opinion, as it creates this confusion, the illusion that Postgres stores with an offset/zone when in fact Postgres stores only in UTC. The Question explicitly asked for the data *as it is stored* in a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.  Postgres always stores values in that column in UTC.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I had tried the following : OffsetDateTime deadline = resultSet.getObject("deadline_date", OffsetDateTime.class); ,And got date as 2018-05-04T00:00Z But in DB the date is  2018-05-03 19:00:00-05.I need to get the date as in DB.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

Postgres ***always* stores a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)** in a column of type [`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html).

- Going into the database, adjusted to UTC.
- Going out, UTC.

**Beware of your database access tool**: It may alter the retrieved UTC value, applying a zone/offset adjustment. This creates the illusion of the moment having been stored in that zone/offset when in fact it was stored in UTC.

Use objects, not strings, to exchange date-time values with your database.

Use only *java.time* classes, never the legacy `Date`/`Calendar`. For UTC moments, use [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

The other Answers are correct in advising you to use objects rather than strings when exchanging date-time values between Java and your database. That is the whole point to [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) and your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver), to [marshal data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) back-and-forth while mediating the differences & details.

However those other Answers incorrectly advise the wrong classes to use in Java.

## UTC

Postgres saves moments only in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Any time zone or offset-from-UTC information accompanying an input to a database column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is used to adjust the value into UTC. Then the UTC value is saved to the database, and the original zone/offset forgotten.

Likewise, when retrieving a value from a database column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, you *always* get a value in UTC.

However, your middleware or tool being used between you and the database may be choose in alter the UTC value in transit, to apply a time zone or offset, thereby adjusting the value. I consider this to be a poor design choice, though I understand the good intentions behind it. But such behavior creates the illusion that a zone/offset was in the stored data when it was not.

Be aware that I am describing Postgres behavior here. The SQL standard defines the data types I discuss here, but not their behavior. The SQL standard barely touches on the issues of date-time, unfortunately. So various database implementations differ in their behavior. The adjust-to-UTC behavior of Postgres makes sense to me. But note that if you care about a date-time value’s original zone/offset, you must store that yourself in a separate column.

On the Java side, just use `Instant` for sending and retrieving a moment from a database column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Sending.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

Retrieving.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class );
```

You can adjust from UTC to some particular time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

If you were working in your business logic with an `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` object, extract an `Instant` by calling their `toInstant` method.

```
Instant instant = myZonedDateTime.toInstant() ;  // Extract an `Instant` object, effectively adjusting from some particular time zone to UTC.
```

## Unzoned

An entirely different kind of date-time is one intentionally lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, this kind does *not* represent a specific moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. This type represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours (the range of various time zones).

For this kind of date-time:

- In Java, use `LocalDateTime` class.
- In Postgres, use `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` type.

When an input is sent to a column of this type in Postgres, any accompanying zone/offset information is ignored. The date and time-of-day are taken as-is and stored directly in the database. When retrieved you get the same date and time-of-day, with no adjustment to any particular time zone.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: "Going out, UTC" is wrong. It is going out adjusted to the client's time zone.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Nope, the value is stored and retrieved in UTC. Your intervening access tool such as psql or database driver may choose to dynamically apply a zone/offset adjustment. **Do not conflate your access tool with the database itself.** You can avoid this kind of imposed adjustment easily in JDBC by calling `myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class )` to get the UTC value as it was stored in the database.

Comment: It seems we are both right and wrong. If the client and server send data through the binary protocol, then indeed UTC values are sent. But if the client and server send data in text format, the conversion happens on the server. The JDBC driver does **not** use the binary format by default. Additionally:  `getObject(...,Instant.class);` is (currently) not supported by the Postgres JDBC driver, it results in "*conversion to class java.time.Instant from 93 not supported*"

Comment: @BasilBourque I tried the following : Instant instant = resultSet.getObject( "deadline_date" , Instant.class );
And got this Exception : java.sql.SQLException: unsupported conversion to class java.time.Instant .

Comment: @BasilBourque Is there any way to get the time zone name as in DB? I tried show timezone; in the db and got the timezone : US/Central.
But on executing the same query in my java code I get my local timezone name.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer has no answer. And getObject(..., Instant.class) won't work because instant isn't supported by JDBC, only java.sql.Timestamp which inside stores value as java.util.Date and completely messes up timezones.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in sql, all you have to do is change your query.

```
select to_char(iiv_prescan_invoice_details.deadline_date, "yyyy:MM:dd HH24:MI:SS") as deadline_date 
from iiv_prescan_invoice_details
```

or you can do it in java

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = resultSet.getTimestamp("deadline_date").toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println("Date Time: " + dateTime);
```

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the *wrong* class to use for a database column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. That class lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, so it does *not* represent a moment, and is *not* a point on the timeline. Use that class for a database column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. (“without” versus “with”)